# Show hide controls Based on DropDown Change Event

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

We have one inventory page, where we need to fill value for 70 columns i.e 70 diff type of controls.

But the customer want to enter the mandatory column based on a Specific Drop-down type selection and he also don't want to view the non mandatory controls. He also want a page to map which column is mandatory for which type

**Example:**

For  **Student** College is a mandatory field and Company is a non mandatory field the customer want to see the **college** Text-box alone not the **Company** Text-box
 For Employee College and Company Both are mandatory So the customer want to see both the text box.

Tried using jQuery for few controls the performance is good but for 70 controls the performance is bad. is there any other way to do it effectively.

70 input controls and 70 labels are there in my page all controls visibility has to be changes based on a single drop-down change event.

Jquery Function;

```
function GetControlVisiblityByAssetID(assetID) {
            var service = getAbsolutePath() + "/Services/CMDBServices.asmx/GetControlVisiblityByAssetID"
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: service,
                data: "{'assetId' : '" + assetID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var reference = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
                    for (var j = 0; j < reference.length; j++) {
                        ControlName[j] = reference[j].ControlName;
                        IsVisible[j] = reference[j].IsVisible;
                        ControlType[j] = reference[j].ControlType;
                        if (IsVisible[j]) {
                            $("\"" + GetSelectorType(ControlType[j]) + "\"[id$=" + ControlName[j] + "]").show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("\"" + GetSelectorType(ControlType[j]) + "\"[id$=" + ControlName[j] + "]").hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

function GetSelectorType(ControlType) {
            switch (ControlType) {
                case 'TextBox':
                    return "input";
                    break;
                case 'DropDown':
                    return "select";
                    break;
                case 'lable':
                    return;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Convert jQuery to vanilla js

Comment: Can To Share me what is Vanila JS. bcs im not aware of it

Comment: Vanilla JS is not anything special; Just raw javascript :p

Comment: Ok Thank U but my majoy problem is im able to do it in Jquery but to find the contols it is taking much time is there any way to fix it

Comment: Raw js is blazing fast (~40 times more than jQuery). [Check here](http://vanilla-js.com/). If all you need is just selecting, you can use `document.querySelectorAll()`. [Have a look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JQuery` for this purpose.

In Jquery use `hide()` , `show()` or `slideToggle()` functions for this purpose.

Since, you dont have particular code, i can not write whole code here.

But for your referance can look at following links:

**1. slideToggle():**

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

**2. hide() :**

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

**3. show() :**

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Hope its helpful.

Comment: I Tried with these things only but the perfomance is not good

Comment: I Added the code To Find the control in the page it is taking time sometimes im getting stopScript Warning msg in IE